# Load image from not refrenced dll in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I working on application with wpf that it works with multi languages. users can put language dll in Languages folder and program load dynamically them. i want to show assembly name with country flag from it. i wrote this code but flage image not show in combobox. how can i do this?

```
        var assemblies = dir.GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        //for each found .dll we will create a model and set its properties and then add to list
        for (int i = 0; i < assemblies.Count(); i++)
        {
            var assemblyName = assemblies[i].Name.Substring(0, assemblies[i].Name.LastIndexOf("."));
            string packUri = string.Format("pack://application:,,,/{0};component/Image/flag.png", assemblyName);
            Uri uri = new Uri(packUri, UriKind.Absolute);

            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

            try
            {
                image.UriSource = uri;
                image.EndInit();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var m = ex.Message;
            }

            CultureAssemblyModel model = new CultureAssemblyModel()
            {
                DisplayText = assemblies[i].Name.Split('.', '_')[2],
                Culture = assemblies[i].Name.Split('.', '_')[1],
                Name = assemblies[i].Name,
                XamlFileName = assemblies[i].Name.Substring(0,                      assemblies[i].Name.LastIndexOf(".")) + ".xaml",FlagImage=image
            };
```

Comment: IMO, you must first load the assembly by `Assembly.LoadFrom()` after the resource will be available by pack uri.

Comment: thank's Hamlet. But how can i access that resource?

Comment: As mentioned in my comment - by pack uri.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try to use MEF for this kind of thing.

I will allow you to:

- Load your dll dynamically in a very easy way
- Recompose your classes based on contracts
- Let your user (the creator of the DLL) extend your application

This might simplify a lot on the loading part but it is of course a bit more complex on the dll creation part.